# Convert control-character (^F) to ascii string ("^F")

Tags: functions

I'm writing a vimscript function that converts a single ASCII control-character in the range 1 - 26 (e.g. `^F`) to its two-character printable representation (e.g. `^` `F`).

Currently, I have:

```
func! CtrlCharStr(arg)
  let cntrl = matchstr(a:arg, '^[[:cntrl:]]$')
  let ascii = char2nr(cntrl)

  if ascii >= 1 && ascii <= 26
    let letter = nr2char(ascii + 64)
    return '^'.letter
  else
    return ''
  endif
endf
```

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

The reason I'm doing this in the first place is to check whether the given character appears in `'indentkeys'`, e.g. `!^F`, and should re-indent the current line instead of being inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the `strtrans()` function. From `:h strtrans()`:

```
The result is a String, which is {expr} with all unprintable
characters translated into printable characters |'isprint'|.
Like they are shown in a window.  Example:
        echo strtrans(@a)
This displays a newline in register a as "^@" instead of
starting a new line.
```

As an example, you could try this function:

```
fu! CtrlCharStr(arg) abort
    return a:arg =~# '^[[:cntrl:]]$'
    \?         strtrans(a:arg)
    \:         ''
endfu
```

Or without continuation lines:

```
fu! CtrlCharStr(arg) abort
    return a:arg =~# '^[[:cntrl:]]$' ? strtrans(a:arg) : ''
endfu
```

If the argument passed to the function is a single control character, the function should return its caret notation.
Otherwise, it should return an empty string.

`?:` is a ternary operator used to build a conditional expression. The latter evaluates to different values depending on whether an arbitrary test succeeds:

```
expr = test ? value1 : value2
```

If `test` is true, then `expr` evaluates to `value1`, otherwise to `value2`.

For more information, see `:h expr1`.

Comment: Great! `strtrans()` is exactly what I was looking for.